# Cannot run flyway commands in php

Tags: php, flyway

I am trying to run some flyway commands inside a function from php.
it's a simple clean function that goes something like this:

```
function clean_schema() {
    chdir('my/current/path');
    try{
        exec('flyway clean', $output, $result);}
    catch(Exception $e){
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

Now as output and result I get an empty array and the error 127. I've looked around and found that that means that I do not have flyway set as a system environment, but if I run the flyway clean command directly in my cmd shell program, it works just fine.

Comment: Try to use the absolute path to your executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Error code 127](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) means the executable was not found in the given context. Your shell differs from one executed from the web context, probably because your `PATH` environment variable is [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

Have you tried executing the app with an [absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) instead? Learn where the executable is first:

```
which flyway
```

then:

```
exec('/absolute/path/flyway clean', $output, $result);
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so very much, it works with setting the absolute path, I thought that I just had to change my current working path from php for it to work. I am really grateful.

Comment: Happy to help, please mark this answer as the solution then.

Comment: I find it weird that I can run the `which flyway` command in shell but in the `exec()` function it returns null, but if I run `which php` they work in both cases..I also tried entering the php interactive mode in my shell, and when I echo there the exec function directly, with flyway, it returns the path, but when I echo it inside my code it returns, again, null.

Comment: Interactive php in shell directly is still different from the web context.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210164/cannot-run-shell-which-command-in-php-code for a duplicated question about using `which`