# Cannot run shell (which) command in PHP code

Tags: php, shell, ssh, flyway

So I am working with Flyway and I run specific commands using PHP exec() function:

```
exec('/path/absolute/flyway info');
```

These commands work as long as I specify the absolute path, but that may vary depending on the machines that it will be working on. That is why I want to use a variable which determines that absolute path, through the command `exec('which flyway')`.

The thing is that this returns a null value, even though when I write it directly in shell I get the desired result. I also tried using the php interactive shell `php -a`, where if I run the command `echo exec('which flyway')` it also returns the desired path, altough when I write it directly in my code, I get the NULL result.

Note that if I want to verify the absolute path of php (`which php`), I can do that in the shell, php -a or in my code, and it returns the desired result in all three cases. So the `which flyway` command is the only one that has a null result in my code.

Can anyone please help me in this matter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`which` uses the same path variables which are used when you run the command without the absolute path. So, either you could use them directly (because they are on the path) and would not need `which` after all, or `which` is not able to find the executables after all.

Additionally, keep in mind that not all hosters allow to run arbitrary from a PHP process. You should not built your application on such a foundation

Comment: the flyway commands do not work if I do not specify the hardcoded absolute path.. that is why I want to create a variable to replace it, so it is not hardcoded anymore. I had a person tell me that I could do something like `exec('$(which flyway) info', $output, $result)`, but that also returns a null response

Comment: Then why don't you use it? Yes, it cannot be done through `which`, but probably you just need to configure that variable manually

Comment: I told you, because I do not want to have a hardcoded path and use a dynamic variable instead. PS I edited the comment from above.

Comment: I understand that, but as I wrote, `which` cannot be used unless you place `flyway` into the `PATH` variable of your server

Comment: Make the path to `flyway` a configuration option, that should be provided in the installation phase of your system or a constructor parameter if your project is a library.